# Array length is incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
public toggle(event): void {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.parentNode.children);
```

html:

```
<div class="activity-header" timeline-item ng-click="vm.toggle($event);">
```

So when I click the header I pass in the event, grab the parent element and than it's children.

When I check the log I see:

> HTMLCollection(2) [div.activity-header, div.activity-footer]

When I click to expand the array in the log I see:

```
HTMLCollection(2) [div.activity-header, div.activity-footer]
0: div.activity-header
1: div.activity-body
2: div.activity-body
3: div.activity-body
4: div.activity-body
5: div.activity-body
6: div.activity-body
7: div.activity-body
8: div.activity-footer
length: 9
```

The body elements are rendered from a ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities.items track by activity.id" class="activity-body">
```

Just for reference the html structure is like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="activity-header" timeline-item ng-click="vm.toggle($event);">
        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities.items track by activity.id" class="activity-body">
        <div class="contact-moment">
            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
            <div class="contact-moment-body">
                <b>{{vm.activity.channel | activityChannel}}: <span ng-bind-html="vm.case.title || (vm.activity | activityTitle)"></span></b>
                <br />
                <div ng-include="'/CustomerService/ActivityTimeline/ActivityTemplates/' + activity.type + '.html'" id="{{activity.type}}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity-footer">
        <md-button>
            Button 1
        </md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the issue is that Javascript doesn't count the `activity-body` elements while they are there.

Comment: BTW `HTMLCollection != Array`

Comment: Oh yea? I thought a collection would be a array. Hm, that might be an issue...

Comment: _"An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed."_

Comment: @PeterBoomsma If I'm not mistaken, you'll need `Array.from` to iterate it using `Array` functions like `forEach`, `filter`...!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you are correct.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Yup. It's a common confusion.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you `console.log`, the `div.activity-body` aren't rendered to the DOM yet. When you expand the list of DOM nodes, the body elements have been rendered, and the `event.currentTarget.parentNode.children` reference has been updated to reflect this.

What's written to the log is just a snapshot - when you interact with it, it gets updated to reflect the real world.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. That makes sense. So when I expand the HTML collection in the log it checks the collection again and updates it. Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`children` is a **live** list and `console.log()` holds a reference to an object just like most other JavaScript.

The order of events is:

1. Log `children`: It has 2 elements in it.
2. Add 7 more elements to it.
3. Click the expand icon in the Console which causes the object to be reexamined, so all 9 elements are shown.